# I am trying to check if a database exists using sqlcmd.exe via batch command and will do other things based on the result

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

I am writing a batch file that checks the existence of a database, and based on the outcome batch will execute other statements.

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%S IN ( `sqlcmd.exe -S %server% -d master -U %username% -P !password! ^
    -Q "set nocount on; select count(*) from dbo.sysdatabases where [name]='$(inputDatabase)'" -v inputDatabase="%databaseName%"` ) DO (
 SET existsDB=%%S
 )
if !existsDB! EQU 1 (
    REM DO SOMETHING
) else (
    REM DO SOMETHING
)
```

Dynamic assignment of database name fails. Returns the "Sqlcmd: 'TestDB': Invalid argument. Enter '-?' for help."

I would appreciate any directions to solve the issue.

Comment: Why not just do `...where name='%databaseName%'`?  Also, [according to this page](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/sqlcmd-database-exists/17597.html) you could use `sp_helpdb` to list your databases.  Instead of the `for` loop as you are using now, try `sqlcmd -S %server% -U %user% -P !password! -Q "EXEC sp_helpdb" | find /i "%databaseName%" >NUL && ( rem Database exists ) || ( rem Database does not exist. )`

Comment: @rojo: This should not be used since it could result into false finds. For example you are looking for database "test" and your server holds database named "test1". In this case your command indicates that "test" database exists.

Comment: @frantakocourek So use `findstr` and set word boundaries, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code checks not only the database name, but also the login credentials and the server name.

```
SET _chk_DB=server
FOR /F "usebackq" %%S IN (`sqlcmd.exe -S %_svr% -d master -U %_usr%
-P %_psw% ^
-Q "set nocount on; select count(*) from dbo.sysdatabases where
[name]='%_dtb%'" `) DO (  
SET _chk_DB=%%S  
)
IF [%_chk_DB%]==[server] SET _returncode=1
IF [%_chk_DB%]==[login] SET _returncode=2
IF [%_chk_DB%]==[0] SET _returncode=4
```